# How to print first and last row in an array using C

Tags: c

I have m x m array and i am trying to find out first and last row of a given matrix (using C) which is

```
e.g mat[3][3]={1,2,3,
               4,5,6,
               7,8,9};
```

But i could not figure out how to get first and last row using c. If some have the algorithm then please share with me.

Comment: First row is `mat[0][i]` and last row is `mat[2][i]`, i ∈ [0,2]. For a matrix `M x N`, first is `mat[0][i]` and last is `mat[M-1][i]`, i ∈ [0,N-1].

Comment: Thank for the reply, But i want general

Comment: Do you know how to print the whole array in C?

Comment: take a look at this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm

Comment: Maybe you could explain in a little bit more detail what exactly you want to have; what is the input, what do you want to have as output. Just posting the same comment to each answer doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that does this for you

```
void print_first_last(int **array, int height, int width) {
    unsigned v;
    for (v = 0; v < width; v++) {
        printf("%d ", array[0][v]);
    }
    puts("");

    for (v = 0; v < width; v++) {
        printf("%d ", array[height - 1][v]);
    }
}
```

```
//main
print_first_last(mat, 3, 3);
```

Comment: You do understand that `int mat[3][3]` is not equivalent to `int **array` right? `int mat[3][3]` is `int (*)[3]` (a *pointer to an array of 3 int*) not a *pointer-to-pointer-to-int*.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes I understand this, but OP said he wanted it to be "general" and without further information, this is the best option

Comment: You could use nested loops with an unusual increment on the outer: `for (int u = 0; u < height; u += height - 1) { for (int v = 0; v < width; v++) printf("%d ", array[u][v]); putchar('\n'); }`.  This has the additional merit of putting the newline after each row of output.  Also, in C99, the function signature could be `void print_first_last(int height, int width, int array[height][width])` which will work with real arrays of any size.  Your code with `int **` only works with arrays of pointers, which are not the same as ordinary 2D arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have m*m matrix, so first row will be `mat[0][1]` to `mat[0][m-1]` and last row will be `mat[m-1][0]` to `mat[m-1][m-1]`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("%d ", mat[0][i]); //first row
}

for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("%d ", mat[m-1][i]); //Last row
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are printing the matrix in the scope where it is declared, you can use the `sizeof` operator to print the first and last rows (or you pass that information to a function):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int mat[3][3]={{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
    unsigned int i;

    /* printf first row */
    printf ("array[0] : ");
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof *mat/sizeof **mat; i++)
        printf (" %d", mat[0][i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    /* print last row */
    printf ("array[%lu] : ", sizeof mat/sizeof *mat - 1);
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof *mat/sizeof **mat; i++)
        printf (" %d", mat[sizeof mat/sizeof *mat - 1][i]);
    putchar ('\n');


    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_sizeof
array[0] :  1 2 3
array[2] :  7 8 9
```

**4X4 Same Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int mat[][4]={{1,2,3,4}, {3,4,5,6}, {6,7,8,9}, {9,8,7,6}};
    unsigned int i;

    /* printf first row */
    printf ("array[0] : ");
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof *mat/sizeof **mat; i++)
        printf (" %d", mat[0][i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    /* print last row */
    printf ("array[%lu] : ", sizeof mat/sizeof *mat - 1);
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof *mat/sizeof **mat; i++)
        printf (" %d", mat[sizeof mat/sizeof *mat - 1][i]);
    putchar ('\n');


    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_sizeof
array[0] :  1 2 3 4
array[3] :  9 8 7 6
```

**Passing to a Function**

To print the first and last from a function, you must pass the same information. At a minimum, you will always have to pass (1) a pointer to the array, (2) the type and/or sizeof type, (3) the number of rows, and (4) the number of columns. You may be able to specify the type, size and number of columns by passing a pointer to type (combining information for 1, 2 & 4), but that must be passed in some fashion. If your array is filled dynamically, then you will have your count of rows x columns from counting your input. If you declare a static array, you have the constant. Either way, that is a required part of the information. E.g.:

```
#define NCOL 4
...
int main (void) {
    int mat[][NCOL]={{1,2,3,4}, {3,4,5,6}, {6,7,8,9}, {9,8,7,6}};
    ...
    print_1st_last (mat, sizeof mat/sizeof *mat);
    ...
}

void print_1st_last (int (*mat)[NCOL], size_t m)
{
    size_t i;

    printf ("array[0] : ");
    for (i = 0; i < NCOL; i++)
        printf (" %d", mat[0][i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    /* print last row */
    printf ("array[%zu] : ", m - 1);
    for (i = 0; i < NCOL; i++)
        printf (" %d", mat[m - 1][i]);
    putchar ('\n');

}
```

Comment: Thank for the reply, But i want general purpose algorithm. Above is just an example. What if it's 4 x 4 matrix.

Comment: Type in a 4x4 -- it will work fine. The key is you must have some way to determine the size. You determine with `sizeof` in the scope of declaration (and pass that info to a function if you are processing in a function),

Comment: As written, you're tied to different functions for different matrix widths — e.g. `matrix[any_size][4]` and `matrix[other_size][5]` — aren't you?  C99 allows you to avoid that (see my comment to another answer).

Comment: Yes, that was necessitated by the declaration of `(*)[CONST]` rather than as `**`. I agree with your nested loop approach from your comment for C99. Here the understanding was the OP had provided a static declaration of known size at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

First you should understand how the matrix is organised in memory. [image]

(Taken from http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/23two-dim-array-memory-layout.html)

2 Ways you can use - As a 2D array or as a pointer accessed location. Note that everytime the row index moves, the value being accessed has to move by the number of columns in the matrix. Hence accessing the value using a pointer is more intuitive, but is really subjective.

**Case1**: If 2D array, and ROWS and COLUMNS are known, use the below to print any row.

```
//row is the row# to print, ex, 0 or ROWS-1 
for i from 0 to COLUMNS-1
    output = mat[row][i]
```

**Case2**: If you have input mat as a pointer to the first value in the array organised as a 2D matrix, use as below

```
//row is the row# to print, ex, 0 or ROWS-1
for i from 0 to COLUMNS-1
    output = mat[row*COLUMNS + i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("%d ", mat[0][i]); //first row
}

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("%d ", mat[2][i]); //Last row
}
```

Comment: You need a pair of newlines somewhere in there, don't you?

Comment: Thank for the reply, But i want general purpose algorithm. Above is just an example. What if it's 4 x 4 matrix.

Comment: u must define the row and column size than u can make genral

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
{
    // mat[0][i] first row
    // mat[m - 1][i] last row
}
```